# Mounting gov registry in external database from ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm using ESB 4.6.0 and GREG 4.5.3. running on the same host. ESB has an offset of 1 and GREG has an offset of 2. I followed the instructions here http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Governance+Partition+in+a+Remote+Registry

The remote mount appears to be working. However, when I click Source View in the ESB management interface, I see a "System Error Occured" message with "java.lang.Exception: Error while retrieving Synapse configuration details". The ESB log has this error message "The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) local://services/ConfigServiceAdmin {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}". Similarly, the other links in the management interface under the Service Bus category are not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the registry.xml of your ESB, you will need to update the port of the registry URL to reflect the port-offset. By default this is 9443, I guess your value will have to be 9445.
If this doesn't resolve your issue, look at the wso02carbon.log - there are probably other errors occuring during ESB start-up.

Comment: Playing with ESB registry configuration recently, I found out that in some instance the synapse-conf folder in repository/deployment/server/ was completely wiped. This appears to occur when the registry settings are not correctly configured, especially registry mount. Copying a backup of the folder usually resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some thing missing in document.

I was able to resolve this issue by updating the domain thing based on the product and did not kept it wso2.carbon.domain as is by default.

```
<parameter name="domain">wso2.esb.domain</parameter>
```

this solved my problem and i am running all WSO2 products this way.

Hope it solves your problem if you are still stuck.